# Can't see metrics of Load balancers in azure monitor

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-load-balancer

I'm unable to see metrics of load balancer using azure monitor.It shows an error.

[image]

There's no metrics tab (under monitoring category) inside the resource view as well.please refer the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-troubleshoot#error-retrieving-data-message-on-dashboard)**,

> This problem may happen when your dashboard was created with a metric
> that was later deprecated and removed from Azure. To verify that it is
> the case, open the Metrics tab of your resource, and check the
> available metrics in the metric picker. If the metric is not shown,
> the metric has been removed from Azure. Usually, when a metric is
> deprecated, there is a better new metric that provides with a similar
> perspective on the resource health.

**Solution:** Update the failing tile by picking an alternative metric for your chart on dashboard

Comment: every other metrics also gives the same error. I've followed this documentation as well.